# async pipe with observable in angular 4

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5

I am new to angular and started leaning angular 4. Data not binding with `ngfor` directive on a component using the async pipe. Please help

user service uses HTTP request to get data from API:

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { User } from "../Models/user";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    get(url: string): Observable<User[]> {
        return this.http.get(url)
            .map(response => response.json() as User[])
            // .do(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

Here i am using observable User[] interface for user list:

user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../Services/user.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import { User } from '../Models/user';
import { DBOperation } from '../Shared/enum';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Global } from '../Shared/global';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/Components/user.component.html'
})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('modal') modal: ModalComponent;
    users$: Observable<User[]>;
    user: User;
    msg: string;
    indLoading: boolean = false;
    userForm: FormGroup;
    dbops: DBOperation;
    modalTitle: string;
    modalBtnTitle: string

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService) 
   { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
        Id: [''],
        UserName: ['', Validators.required],
        Password: ['', Validators.required],
        FirstName: ['', Validators.required],
        LastName: ['', Validators.required],
        Gender: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.LoadUsers();
    }
    LoadUsers(): void {
        this.indLoading = true;
        this.users$ = this.userService.get('http://localhost:29712/api/userapi/');
        this.indLoading = false;
    }   
}
```

Template for the async pipe to subscribe observable users variable:

user.component.html

```
<div class='panel panel-primary'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
        User Management
     </div>
     <div class='panel-body'>
         <div class='table-responsive'>
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" *ngIf="indLoading"><img src="../../images/loading.gif" width="32" height="32" /> Loading...</div>
        <div *ngIf='users && users.length==0' class="alert alert-info" role="alert">No record found!</div>
        <table class='table table-striped' *ngIf='users && users.length'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
                    <td>{{user.FirstName}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.LastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.Gender}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="msg" role="alert" class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
        {{msg}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you are subscribing, you should not need the async pipe.

Comment: Your `/api/userapi/` request will be executed twice

Comment: i'd check if `response => response.json() as IUser[]` resolves to null. are you sure that service responds with the same data structure as your IUser is?

Comment: @deezg His response is correct. Look at template `ngIf="users && users.length"` where `users` is Observable

Comment: Yes, I am also getting users json array in LoadUsers function

Comment: @yurzui well, he didn't actually say what does 'data don't bind' mean? does it mean that table isn't being shown at all (`ngIf` you mention don't resolve to `true`) or table is shown but no rows rendered within table?

Comment: i mean, this kind of thing should be architectured with smart/dumb components, have `@Input()` in dumb component set to `Observable` and check things in `OnChanges`. But now its interesting to see why it doesn't work when setup this way.

Comment: @deezgd yes table isn't being shown at all

Comment: @yurzui ah but then of course, you're right. i was focusing on `ngFor` as he said in question. but sure, `ngIf` with `users` being Observable is a problem.

Comment: @deezg you are right, users is Observable i removed the condition and now users list showing

Comment: @Sajan credits go to @yurzui. He pointed out about `ngIf` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using async. Try removing susbcribe. on your original code. Here's a [video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-using-the-async-pipe-in-angular-2) of something similar. It's really helpful to use $ for Observable properties...

Comment: Then he should change this part `let user of users | async` as well in template.

Comment: Its giving error that Type 'IUser' is not assignable to Type 'Observable<IUser[]>' because this.users is 'Observable<IUser[]>' Type

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines - Don't place I for interfaces or _ for private instances... I also normally put $ on end of variable to indicate it's an observable. So I'd have let user of users$ | async and change property in class

Comment: Not getting any error. Its not binding user list to template

Answer (score 0):

Your *ngIf is making issue you cannot check directly your observable length without async pipe. Try this,

```
*ngIf="(users$ | async)?.length==0"
```

Comment: But length is 0 means there is no data and it will call one more http call

Comment: I would resolve async pipe once by using `users$ | async as users`

Comment: Why it call one more api. this.loads function will fire when ngOnInit runs and it will going to call the api.

Comment: We will have two subscriptions within ngIf and ngFor

Comment: @yurzui just to add ref to the docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf . Part with 'storing conditional result in a variable'